# While loop doesnt show the right output

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop, do-while

I have created a while loop to get the following output =

Enter the name of the Player -1- Alex,

Enter the name of the Player -2- Peter,

Enter the name of the Player -3- ...
...

However, I am not able to implement correctly the while loop because I obtain always the
same value = 1. Can someone help me?
code=

```
 ------------ 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import random as random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
import math
import statistics
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.style as style
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt
import time
import os

 

   
    #Name of the player for the game
    
    i=1

colonne= ['player_name']

df = []

for player in colonne:
    
    while i<10:
        
        df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Numero': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        player: [str(input("Enter the name of the Player %s " %i)) for player in range(10)],
        }).set_index('Numero')

        i=i+1
    
    
    
    df.append(df_1)

df1 = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
------

output:

Enter the name of the Player 1 Alex
Enter the name of the Player 1 Peter
Enter the name of the Player 1
```

Comment: Do you mean `% player`, not `% i`?

Comment: The `... for player in range(10)` loop runs ten times while `i` is still 1.  As @Carcigenicate commented, did you mean to use `player` as the value, instead of `i`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, it works! Thanks for both of you

Answer (score 0):

An easier way might be using .format() in addition to creating a list of all players first and then converting that to a dataframe at the end. Please see the below example. Using the .format() can avoid issues with different data types in strings.

```
import pandas as pd

players = []  # empty list 
i = 1  # initial count and player number 

while i < 11:

    players.append(input(('Input the name of Player {}').format(i)))  # take input and append to list 

    i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(players, columns=['Player Name'], index=[i+1 for i in range(10)])  # convert list to dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop you are using a list comprehension which is looping through the numbers (players) in range(10).

However, you are using i for the number of the player. Not sure if you meant to have both the while loop and the list comprehension loop, but if you did then you simply need to change:

```
input("Enter the name of the Player %s " %i)
```

To:

```
input("Enter the name of the Player %s " %player)
```

Otherwise all 10 versions of the loop will happen inside the very first while loop, so i is still 1 for the first 10 loops since you haven't reached i = i + 1 yet.

This will ask for 100 lines of input however so you probably didn't mean that, so you can just remove the list comprehension i.e.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Numero': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    player: [input(f"Enter the name of the Player %s " %i)],
    }).set_index('Numero')
```